# Actionscript associative array constructor?

Tags: arrays, actionscript

This seems silly to ask this, but is there a way to make an associative array in actionscript right in the variable declarations?

e.g.

```
private var stages:Array = [
    "name" : "NY Stage",
    "location" : "New York",
    "capacity" : 15000
]
```

Instead, the way I'm doing it is (1): declaring the array up top and then creating the rest of the array in the class constructor:

```
private var stages:Array;

public function PlayStage(){
    stages["name"] = "NY Stage";
    stages["location"] = "New York";
    stages["capacity"] = 15000;
}
```

Can I do something like the top (without creating an object)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Array` to create an associative array. If you read the [`Array`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#) documentation, it specifically recommends against the practice.

Use an `Object` instead. Here's a link to the documentation on how to create associative arrays:

[Associative arrays in AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7eea.html)

To iterate over the keys of an associative array (this would be used to get the length as well), you can use this:

```
var oObj:Object = { "name" : "pear", "color" : "yellow" };

...

for ( var key:* in oObj )
{
    // do something with the key or increment a counter, etc.
}
```

Comment: ah, I see. i also see that object doesn't have any methods like arrays (slice, splice, length), which is why i was hoping to use associative arrays (instead of turning objects into arrays when needed or looping). what's the easiest way to get the length of an object's properties?

Comment: @Prodikl I updated my answer with a small `for` loop that you can use to iterate over the keys. You can use this method to create a function that returns the length of an associative array that you pass in.

Comment: that's awesome, thanks! and accessing the value would just be oObj[key], right?

Answer (score 1):

Like xxbbcc said, Associative arrays are essentially objects in AS3, so the shorthand object construction will work:

```
private var stages:Object = {
    "name" : "NY Stage",
    "location" : "New York",
    "capacity" : 15000
}
```